# LocalDateTime plusDays() dont work when is the end of the month

Tags: android, date, kotlin, localdatetime

I'm testing my app today(may 30) whith a custom hour and minute:

```
var today=LocalDateTime.now().withHour(hour).withMinute(minute).withSecond(0).withNano(0)
```

But, when i do:

```
 today=today.plusDays(1) //today is: 2022-03-30T10:04
```

It's return in the Log:

```
2022-03-30T10:04
```

**UPDATE**: Here is the complete code. I'm testing on Android 8.1.0

```
fun calcEndTime(hour: Int, minute: Int, initinmilliseconds:Long):Long {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        var endtime =LocalDateTime.now().withHour(hour).withMinute(minute).withSecond(0).withNano(0)
        val now = LocalDateTime.now().withSecond(0).withNano(0)
        val inittime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(initinmilliseconds).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime()
        val days=inittime.dayOfMonth-now.dayOfMonth

        if(days==1||days<0){
            endtime=endtime.plusDays(1)
            Log.d("ZXCV","if ${endtime}")
        }

        if (endtime.isBefore(now)) {
            endtime = endtime.plusDays(1)
        }
        return endtime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli()
        }
    }
```

Comment: your code works fine on my AndroidStudio, maybe you are returning the wrong date? could you add your complete function?

Comment: @Ric17101 check the update

Comment: do you have sample input on this function calcEndTime(hour, minute, iniinmilliseconds)? especially with iniinmilliseconds

Comment: @Ric17101 set endtime manually to: 2022-03-30T06:00 and initinmilliseconds=1648706400000

Comment: @Ric17101 any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried doing it this way, it seems to work just fine

```
fun calcEndTime(hour: Int, minute: Int, initinmilliseconds: Long): LocalDateTime {
    var endtime = LocalDateTime.now().withHour(hour).withMinute(minute).withSecond(0).withNano(0)
    val now = LocalDateTime.now().withSecond(0).withNano(0)
    val inittime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(initinmilliseconds).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime()
    val days = inittime.dayOfMonth - now.dayOfMonth

    if (days == 1 || days < 0) {
        endtime = endtime.plusDays(1)
        Log.d("ZXCV", "if ${endtime}")
    }

    if (endtime.isBefore(now)) {
        endtime = endtime.plusDays(1)
        Log.d("ZXCV2", "if ${endtime}")
    }
    return endtime//.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli() // try commenting this out to return LocalDateTime instead
}
```

sample usage:

```
binding.buttonFirst.setOnClickListener {
        val hour = 10
        val minute = 4
        var today = calcEndTime(hour, minute, 1648706400000)

        var test = "TESTING today" + "\n"
        test += today.toString() + "\n"


        today = today.plusDays(1)
        test += today.toString() + "\n"
        binding.textviewFirst.text = test
    }
```

Screenshot[image]